# Display div by id through js

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is it possible to change this to display an element loaded later on in the document:

```
function tracksinfox_{$page_trackid}()
{
    document.getElementById('tracksinfoxshow_{$page_trackid}').innerHTML = 'get stuff here';
}
```

In the place of "get stuff here", I would like to display a div by id, but the div is created later in the page load using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery's on(), you can add event handlers to elements which are added later to the document. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: As of 1.7 live() is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, live() is deprecated, but on() is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the function perform after document ready by document.onreadystatechange:

```
document.onreadystatechange=function() { 
    if(document.readyState == 'complete'){ 
        tracksinfox_{$page_trackid}();
    }
}
```

or just use window.onload event simply;

```
window.onload = tracksinfox_{$page_trackid};
```

but there's one more thing you have to know, if you like to perform two or more function after document ready, you can do it like this:

```
run_after_document_ready( tracksinfox_{$page_trackid} );
run_after_document_ready( somethingelse );
run_after_document_ready( somethingelse2 );

function run_after_document_ready( callback ) {
    callback_saver = window.onload;
    window.onload = function (){
        if ( typeof callback_saver == "function" ){
            callback_saver();
        }
        callback();
    }
}
```

or just use the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(tracksinfox_{$page_trackid});
$(document).ready(somethiselse);
$(document).ready(somethiselse2);
```

NOTICE: window.onload has a little different with document.ready, for more information, you should to find the documents about window.onload, document.onreadystatechange and the jquery document ready.

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery and doing something like the following.  It establishes a callback method that will be called when a new element with `id="info"` is added to the DOM, then it adds a new DIV with `id="info"`, which causes the callback function to be executed.  The callback function unregisters itself (thus it will only ever be called once), then sets the `update-me` DIV's text based on the new DIV.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="update-me">I will be updated.</div>

        <script language="javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {

            $("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", "#info", function(e){
                $("body").off("DOMNodeInserted", "#info");
                $("#update-me").text( $(e.target).text() );
            });

            $("body").append("<div id='info'>I have changed.</div>");                

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```